# Entity Framework 4.2 Table Valued Functions

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, user-defined-functions

Are these supported? I can't find a definite answer.

Comment: I changed tag to EFv4.1 because EFv4.2 is just bug fixing of 4.1 and it doesn't need separate tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not Yet. A user still asks for that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/01/ef-4-2-released.aspx#10232490

Definitive source: [EF 4.2 Released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx)

> What’s Not in This Release?
>
> As covered earlier this release is just a small update to the DbContext & Code First runtime. The features that were included in **EF
>   June 2011 CTP require changes to the Core Entity Framework Libraries**
>   that are part of the .NET Framework and will ship at a later date.

Form the [June CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx) we have that:

> You can now add table-valued functions to your entity data model. A
>   table-valued function is similar to a stored procedure, but the result
>   of executing the table-valued function is composable, meaning you can
>   use it as part of a LINQ query.